# setResult() working improperly

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities : one is launcher (Act1) and the other (Act2) allows the user to change app settings (which I save using preferences). Act1 shows current settings and user can open Act2 from it. Now, when the user opens Act2, changes settings and returns to Act1, I want the UI of Act1 to upgrade accordingly. This however should happen only if the settings were changed.

So, I am using `startActivityForResult()` to start Act2 and `setResult()` in Act2 right at the spot where I edit my preferences. Code is below :

**Act1.java** :

```
Intent m_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Act2.class);
startActivityForResult(m_intent, 1);
```

**Act2.java** :

```
final Intent m_intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, m_intent);
```

This works perfectly, although only on my 5.0 running Moto G. It does not work on my Optimus One (custom 4.4.2) or even a 2.3.3 running emulator.

The user can return to Act1 either by device's back button or by a small 'x' in UI (calling finish()). I am also overriding `onBackPressed()` in Act2 for 'reasons'. Considering these and after reading a lot of questions on SO where `setResult()` doesn't work I thought it may have to do something with Activity states. So, I tried this in Act2 :

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        final Intent m_intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, m_intent);

        super.finish();
    }
```

and tried to read resultCode in `onActivityResult()` in Act1. It returned `RESULT_OK` in 5.0 but still `RESULT_CANCELLED` on other two devices. It seems I can't make Act2 return `RESULT_OK` on my old phone or emulator ! Any ideas why is this happening....?

**Edit 1:**
Code for onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("res", requestCode + "   " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            can_proceed_click = false;
            readPrefs(true);

            // bat update
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                removeSmLayout(0);
                animateIconToggle(0);
                m_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        makeBatSmIconLayout(false, false);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }

            // saf update
            else if (requestCode == 2) {
                pass_entered = data.getBooleanExtra("pass_entered", false);

                removeSmLayout(1);
                animateIconToggle(1);
                m_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        makeSafSmIconLayout(false, false);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }

            // low update
            else if (requestCode == 3) {
                removeSmLayout(2);
                animateIconToggle(2);
                m_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        makeLowSmIconLayout(false, false);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: onBackPressed() does not call finish. Consider setting your result in `onStop` for example.

Comment: It works fine on 5.0 but still let me check it on onStop()

Comment: But it does return `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` to the calling activity

Comment: @NitroNgb only on my older device and emulator, not on Moto G

Comment: Could you post your entire `onActivityResult()` method? There's no mistake in the code you posted so far.

Comment: UPdated with entire code of onActivityResult

Comment: I still don't see any errors. It returns `RESULT_CANCELLED` for *both* cases for non-5.0 devices?

Comment: yeah...same code, and the log in 5.0 returns [1    -1] and in Optimus One it reurns [1     0]....(-1 = RESULT_OK)....its really annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Well even though I can't see the problem, you can do workaround solution like this:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    final Intent m_intent = new Intent();
    m_intent.putExtra("EXPLICIT_RESULT_CODE", RESULT_OK);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, m_intent);
    super.finish();
}
```

and in Activity A:

```
if(data.getIntExtra("EXPLICIT_RESULT_CODE", RESULT_CANCELLED) == RESULT_OK) {
    //Result is RESULT_OK
}
```

Or just to be extra careful, safegauard it against NullExceptions

```
if(data != null && data.getIntExtra("EXPLICIT_RESULT_CODE", RESULT_CANCELLED) == RESULT_OK) {
    //Result is RESULT_OK
}
```

As you can see, this simply sets up an explicit integer extra and sends it back through the `Intent` object.

Comment: Well your solution is cool, but my data was always null whatsoever and the reason behind that was because both of my activities had launch modes set to 'singleTask'. Why it was working on Lollipop is beyond me. I will look into it after this project but, anyways thank you for your time...

Answer (score 0):

**If anyone else stumbled upon this, here what it was the issue for me:**

if the device has the `do not keep activity alive` option ON, your activity result is not behaving properly, i.e when you pass the RESULT_OK, (which is -1), the caller (parent) activity will get (0) which is RESULT_ERROR

I did turned that off and the setResult now works as expected again.

p.s
the `do not keep activity alive` option can be found in the settings under developer options. the default value is set to OFF by default.